# White space on the right of page on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, responsiveness

I learn to build websites. Now I'm making page to practice and I have a problem. I haven't already made it responsive but I've seen that below 630px width page isn't 100% width anymore. On the right of the page appear white space and I don't know why is that and how to fix that.

Can you help me?

[screen of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxo1z.png)

Comment: can you show us your code please?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if any box (e.g. an `<img>`, a `<span>` or a `<table>`) is wider than width of browser window.

Images does not shrink and words does not break by default. Boxes can not be smaller than all cells in a row together.

Utilize different responsive techniques to avoid overstretching of viewport.

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
} 

a, 
p, 
span {
  hyphens: auto;
}

/* wrap tables in <div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper"> */
.horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Browser's built-in inspectors helps to find types of not shrinkable elements.